# Is the opengl code running on GPU?

Tags: c++, opengl

When there is a program,which consists of normal c++ code and opengl code.
So,both c++ and opengl are compiled and linked to ELF.
And,seemingly they both run on CPU.

Why opengl code has more power to paint on screen than c++ code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why opengl code has more power to paint on screen than c++ code?

Because OpenGL merely sends drawing commands to the GPU, which is then doing the bulk work. Note that there are also OpenGL implementations that are not GPU accelerated and therefore not faster than other software rasterizers running on the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're talking about GLSL, there is no distinction between "C++ code" and "OpenGL code". It's all just C or C++, depending on what you're building. OpenGL is an API, a library that contains functions that do stuff.

Your code calls OpenGL functions, which are functionally no different from any other C++ function you might call. Functions in C++ do something, based on how they're implemented.

OpenGL functions tell the GPU what to do, using GPU-specific constructs. That's what OpenGL is for: to abstract away the specifics of hardware, so that you can write code that is not hardware-dependent. Your code that calls OpenGL functions should work on any OpenGL implementation that supports your minimum GL version (and extensions, if you're using those).

Similarly, `std::fstream` abstracts away differences between, say, Windows and Linux file access commands. Same API for the user, but it has different implementations on different OS's.

Comment: For extremely small values of two, I suppose.